# I can't open my knowledge base - Bad Argument

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

I try to open my knowledge base and for an hour, I receive a message that indicate this :

[image]

I checked my azure search service and restart the webapp , that's ok, it's running fine.

I have supposed that was because I reached the limit of my plan. I upgraded my plan from a free one (f1) to one with better limits (b1). That do nothing.

Could you help me understand or to find where i'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was my error. It was because i have published by mistake, the bot's files in the same directory than the qnamaker's knowledge base...

I could see this with the Cloud Explorer or the tab App Service explorer in Azure portal.